# How do I check the substring in a query in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, substring, oracle-sqldeveloper

Here is my `Weapons` table:

```
Name / DPS / Style

Noxious Bow / 1000 / Range
Chaotic Staff / 800 / Magic
Armadyl Crossbow / 750 / Range
Saradomin Godsword / 600 / Melee
Dragon Battlestaff / 600 / Magic
Dragon Longsword / 550 / Melee
Elder Shortbow / 500 / Range
Darklight / 400 / Melee
```

Here is what I tried:

```
SELECT Name, DPS, Style
FROM Weapons
HAVING SUBSTRING(Name, 1, 1)='D';
```

I want all `Weapons` that start with the letter D to be displayed. However, this code is giving me a syntax error.

Comment: Which RDBMS (database system) are you using? The SUBSTRING function isn't available in every dialect of SQL. Also, please always include the exact text of any error messages you mention in your question.

Comment: I am using Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: Well, for Oracle, you want the [SUBSTR function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2101.htm), not SUBSTRING.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're using Oracle, the function is [`SUBSTR`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2101.htm), not `SUBSTRING`, and for any RDBMS, you'd need to use `WHERE`, not `HAVING`:

```
SELECT Name, DPS, Style
FROM Weapons
WHERE SUBSTR(Name, 1, 1)='D';
```

`SUBSTRING` would have worked fine in Microsoft SQL Server.

Also, the `LEFT` function is quite widely supported, and might stand a better chance of using an index, if one is defined on `Name`. This will work in Oracle, SQL Server and others:

```
SELECT Name, DPS, Style
FROM Weapons
WHERE LEFT(Name, 1)='D';
```

However, the best option is probably using LIKE, which is widely-supported and flexible, and will also likely use an index on the `Name` column, if one exists, as long as the fixed text you're searching for is at the beginning:

```
SELECT Name, DPS, Style
FROM Weapons
WHERE Name LIKE 'D%';
```

You could probably do with going through a basic SQL tutorial at this stage, and bear in mind that while "SQL" has a standard core, each version is different and you'll need to look for Oracle-specific advice if you're using Oracle.

Comment: Thank-you. I was wondering though, why do index points in SQL start from 1 instead of 0? Don't most programming languages have indexes that start from 0?

Comment: @puretppc Yup, you're quite right. I'm no expert on the history, but when SQL was originally designed, more than forty years ago, it was called SEQUEL, for Structured *English* QUEry Language. That hints that it was meant to be a bit less "programmery" and a little more human, I think. (Similarly, in COBOL, the "COmmon Business Oriented Language", array indexes also start at 1.)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT Name, DPS, Style
FROM Weapons
WHERE Name LIKE 'D%';
```